# how to get multiple keyboard inputs in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a pong like game in html, but every time one player try to move the other movement will stop.

```
//javaScript

var p1axis = 40;
var p2axis = 40;
function input(event) 
{
    var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
    if(x == 115) 
    {
        p1axis += 2;
        document.getElementById("p1").style.top = p1axis + "%";
    }
    if(x == 119) 
    {
        p1axis -= 2;
        document.getElementById("p1").style.top = p1axis + "%";
    }
    if(x == 108) 
    {
        p2axis += 2;
        document.getElementById("p2").style.top = p2axis + "%";
    }
    if(x == 111) 
    {
        p2axis -= 2;
        document.getElementById("p2").style.top = p2axis + "%";
    }
}
```

I expect that both players will be able to play freely.
instead only one can move at once.

Comment: Is `input` a `keypress` event listener ? How is it called ?

Comment: There's nothing here that moves players continuously. Each time you call `input()` it only moves one player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array and add keys as they are pressed. You will have to remove them as the key is released. Also, I just used `keydown` with jQuery, you can also use `keydown` with JavaScript.

```js
var bKeys = [];

$('body').keydown(function(e) {
  if (bKeys.includes(e.which) === false) {
    bKeys.push(e.which);
  }
});

$('body').keyup(function(e) {
  bKeys.pop(e.which);
});
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(bKeys);
}, 15);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remember to click in the body when you run the code

Answer (score 0):

```
var k1 = false, k2 = false, k3 = false, k4 = false;

var p1axis = 40;
var p2axis = 40;

function input(event) 
{
  var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
  if(x == 115 || x == 83) 
  {
    k1 = true;
  }
  if(x == 119 || x == 87) 
  {
    k2 = true;
  }
  if(x == 108 || x == 76) 
  {
    k3 = true;
  }
  if(x == 111 || x == 79) 
  {
    k4 = true;
  }
}

function remove(event) 
{
  var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
  if(x == 115 || x == 83) 
  {
    k1 = false;
  }
  if(x == 119 || x == 87) 
  {
    k2 = false;
  }
  if(x == 108 || x == 76) 
  {
    k3 = false;
  }
  if(x == 111 || x == 79) 
  {
    k4 = false;
  }
}

function move() 
{
  if(k1) 
  {
    p1axis += 1;
    document.getElementById("p1").style.top = p1axis + "%";
  }
  if(k2) 
  {
    p1axis -= 1;
    document.getElementById("p1").style.top = p1axis + "%";
  }
  if(k3) 
  {
    p2axis += 1;
    document.getElementById("p2").style.top = p2axis + "%";
  }
  if(k4) 
  {
    p2axis -= 1;
    document.getElementById("p2").style.top = p2axis + "%";
  }

  setTimeout(move, 20);
}
```

Comment: Please explain this code, as it is a bit useless about what you did